# ADB file explorer building my database problem

Tags: android, database, ddms

In my DDMS tool,i cant build and explore any of my database files and its tables, since there is not permission to access the table. it shows "-rw-rw----" for that table alone... How to overcome the readwrite permission in File explorer? Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can build your database using this jar file from [here](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/). Follow the instructions from this site. Hope this helps you.